# How to recover the previous contents of designer.vb file in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application in VB.net. The code in the `InitializeComponent` function of the designer.vb file got replaced by Visual Studio itself, and now when I hit the start button in Visual Studio, it displays me a simple form with no controls on it.

How can I get my previous code back?

Comment: Back up, undo button, that's about it.

Comment: But the changes have been saved...

Answer (score 3):

This is, unfortunately, quite normal.

You aren't ever supposed to modify the code in the Designer.vb file because the designer automatically regenerates that file every time you use the form designer. This means any changes you have made will be wiped out.

Unless you made a backup of your project file or checked it into your source control system, there is no recovering the old version. You'll just have to recreate it.

Comment: I did the same thing last year and there was nothing I could do about it. Have to start over / last back